# Xamarin Form: Animate using absolute layout bounds

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, portable-class-library

I have a grid in my app:-

```
   <Grid x:Name="BookPagerContainer" IsVisible="false" ColumnSpacing="0" RowSpacing="0" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,1,1,AutoSize" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="XProportional,YProportional,WidthProportional">
        <BoxView Color="{DynamicResource HeaderColor}" Opacity="0.5"></BoxView>
        <Grid x:Name="BookPager" ColumnSpacing="0" RowSpacing="0" HorizontalOptions="Center" Padding="0,5,0,5">
          <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
          </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
```

I want hide/show this grid with animation like going up and down.
 I tried something like this:

```
var animation = new Animation(v => BookPagerContainer.HeightRequest = v,1, AutoSize);
    animation.Commit(this, "SimpleAnimation", 500, 500, Easing.Linear, (v, c) => {
       BookPagerContainer.HeightRequest = AutoSize;
    }, () => false);
```

But it didn't worked.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to move your grid, you can use the `TranslateTo` extension method.

For example :

```
await _BookPagerContainer.TranslateTo(0, _BookPagerContainer.Height);
```